# How to check whether two objects are of the same class?

Tags: java

If I have two objects as follows...

```
ClassA classAInstance = ...
ClassB classBInstance = ...
```

... where ClassB is a direct sub-class (extension) of ClassA and the actual object assigned to 'classAInstance' and 'classBInstance' can be an instance of ClassA, ClassB or a direct or indirect sub-class of ClassA...

How do I then check whether the object assigned to each of 'classAInstance' and 'classBInstance' is of the same Class? Is the following correct...

```
classAInstance.getClass().equals(classBInstance.getClass());
```

... or is it some other property that I should be comparing?

Comment: Just a note that if you need to check whether `ClassB` is **exactly** `ClassA` you are probably violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_Substitution_Principle) or are abusing polymorphism.  Code that relies on an object being a `ClassA` shouldn't care whether it's actually a `ClassB`.

Comment: No no, I want to check whether the Class of the object assigned to `classAInstance` is the same as the Class of the object assigned to `classBInstance`. Question make sense? Is the technique above correct?

Comment: I think the question largely makes sense, my point is that if you need to do this check you almost certainly have a poor design or class hierarchy.  There are valid uses to check the exact type (for example to enforce symmetry in an `equals` implementation) but they are rare.

Comment: Hmm. Noted. And will endeavour to not repeat.

Comment: If ClassB is a subclass of ClassA, then you can't assign an instance of ClassA to classBInstance.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. Yeah, that's correct. Just want to know really that the Class of the two objects is the same and realise I formed my question more complicated than it needed to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's the way to do it...assuming it's the right thing to do.  Of course, as with most reflection, comparing classes at all is pretty fragile, if you're expecting to do any refactoring of how `ClassB`'s hierarchy works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this would work:

```
classAInstance.getClass().equals(classBInstance.getClass())
```

This is the same as

```
classAInstance.getClass() == classBInstance.getClass()
```